# Error using Angle in Julia

Tags: julia, angle, callable

I am simply trying to get the angle of a complex number. To test the angle function provided in Julia I first tried :

```
 angle(1+im)
```

But I get the following error message :

> MethodError: objects of type Float64 are not callable
>
> Stacktrace:  [1] include_string(::String, ::String) at
>   ./loading.jl:515

When I try to ask `typeof(1+im)` Julia answers

> Complex{Int64}

I don't understand what is happening with the angle function. I tried with 1+1*im but I get the same answer.

Could anyone help please?
I could also calculate the angle from coordinates but I'd like to understand Julia language as well.

Thank you

Comment: Try restarting Julia. It works fine for me, so I expect you’ve redefined `angle` accidentally...

Comment: Thank you, indeed when I asked angle i had a variable named angle somewhere in my code, I changed the variable name. I did not think that variables and function, as they are called differently, could be confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's possible to accidentally define a variable with the same name as a built-in function that you don't know about. For example, there's a function called `angle()`, but you can do this:

```
julia> angle=1.5
1.5

julia> angle(1+1im)
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Float64 are not callable

julia> typeof(angle)
Float64
```

Now you can't 'see' the function definition, because your variable is hiding it.

To fix this, you can type:

```
julia> angle=Base.angle
angle (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> angle(1+1im)
0.7853981633974483
```

A good question is, why doesn't Julia tell me I've just overwritten a basic function?

#### Addendum

And the answer (thanks to @Matt in a comment) is that if you use it, and *then* redefine it, you'll get a warning:

```
              _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.6.0 (2017-06-19 13:05 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0

julia> angle(1+2im)
1.1071487177940904

julia> angle=1.5
WARNING: imported binding for angle overwritten in module Main
1.5
```

Comment: Re: _"why doesn't Julia tell me I've just overwritten a basic function?"_ — it will if you call or use it before shadowing it.  But it's nice to be able to use `info` as a variable without any warnings if you're not doing logging, for example.  If it were a warning (or worse an error), then Julia could never export any new functions without breaking existing code.

Comment: Thank you for the precision. Could you please give a bit more details about the code `angle=Base.angle` please? I dont understand how does it work. Thank you. Charline.

Comment: Functions and variables usually belong in modules. The Base module contains much of the basic Julia system (type `names(Base) |> showall` to see them all). Fortunately you don't have to type `Base` before you use them! By typing `Base.angle` you are specifically referring to the function in Base, rather than to your locally defined version. And functions in Julia can be assigned to variables: `angle=Base.function` creates an association between the symbol `angle` and the value `Base.angle`, the function...